# spring security 4 failing to login via custom login url

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I use spring 4.1.6 and spring security 4.0.6
I am trying to do separate login/logout for mainpage and adminpage. The reason is that mainpage is binded with single-sign-on thing via iframe.
Everything working ok with mainpage, but I have troubles implementing login for adminpage.

I put the breakpoint to adminAuthenticationFilter.successfulAuthentication(), and it looks like it's never called.
I tried the following:

```
POST "username" and "password" to "http://localhost:8086/app/admin/login" - returns login page without calling successfulAuthentication()

POST "username" and "password" to "http://localhost:8086/app/login" - returns 404 error

POST via old-way: "j_username" and "j_password" to "http://localhost:8086/app/admin/j_spring_security_check" or "http://localhost:8086/app/j_spring_security_check" - gives 404 error
```

here is my security.xml configuration

```
<http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="mainpageAuthenticationEntryPoint"  create-session="ifRequired" >
    <intercept-url pattern="/mainpage*" access="hasRole('ROLE_SIMPLE')" />
    <custom-filter before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"  ref="mainpageLoginTokenFilter" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="mainpageLogoutSuccessHandler" />
    <headers>
        <frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN" />
    </headers>
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/error.html"/>
    <csrf disabled="true" />
</http>

<http pattern="/adminpage" request-matcher="regex" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="adminAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/adminpage" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <logout logout-url="/admin/logout" success-handler-ref="adminLogoutSuccessHandler"/>
    <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="adminAuthenticationFilter"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="adminAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="loginFormUrl" value="/admin/login"/>
</beans:bean>
```

in web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

in web-context.xml

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/admin/login" view-name="login"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/admin/logout" view-name="login"/>
```

I researched other similar problems but didn't succeed to resolve this problem. Will appreciate any help. Thanks.

**EDIT** 
Changed security.xml to the following. The problem remains

```
<http pattern="/adminpage.*" request-matcher="regex" auto-config="false">
    <intercept-url pattern="/adminpage" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <logout logout-url="/admin/logout" success-handler-ref="administratorLogoutSuccessHandler"/>
    <form-login login-page="/admin/login" login-processing-url="/admin/j_spring_security_check"
                username-parameter="j_username" password-parameter="j_password"
                default-target-url="/adminpage" always-use-default-target="true"
                authentication-success-handler-ref="administratorAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
                authentication-failure-handler-ref="administratorAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="administratorAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.test.AdministratorAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/adminpage"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="administratorAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="com.test.AdministratorAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/admin/login"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: And why should that work.... You have nothing configured for form login... Only showing a page nothing more...

Comment: shouldn't be adminAuthenticationFilter accessed from FORM_LOGIN_FILTER point when posting? Am I missing something really big here?

Comment: Which filter... That isn't configured so how can the form login filter be called if it isn't configured... You don't have a `form-login` element so there is nothing listening. Instead of your custom entry point simply configure a `form-login` inside your `http` element.

Comment: I can't have form-login because I need auto-config="false" and I need custom filter

Comment: auto-config has nothing to do with `form-login`... Also your url should start with `/adminpage` as that is what your admin http block starts with. Next to that you should simple,ment your filter properly and make sure it reacts to the correct URL. If it is just a login then why do you need a custom filter...

Comment: 1. I need custom filter for caching requests and some other things. for case login-logout-login, it will redirect to last logged in url. This is something that is left from previous version of app and I was planning to use it too. 2. App won't start when using both form login and custom filter. Thought that custom entry point binds login form, am I wrong? 3. /adminpage is a path to administration page, i also have other /adminpage/* paths. All they are secured. If I use "/adminpage/login", won't it be protected from anonymous too? Thanks for your time and responses.

Comment: 1. You don't need a custom filter for that, a custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` and additional `LogoutHandler` or `LogoutSuccesHandler` is enough you don't need to override all the functionality. 2. you are wrong and it depends on what your filter is doing. 3. I don't understand what ou are saying here.

Comment: ok, I finally got it.

Comment: using form-login element now (updated post), but the problem still remains. 404 error when login with j_password, j_username to http://localhost:8086/app/admin/j_spring_security_check

Comment: Because that is the wrong url and wrong parameters. Url is `/login` (by default) and parameters `username` and `password`.

Comment: on login i have another one login form. i need separate login/logout

Comment: i mean /login is binded to other login form, i need /admin/login for separate administrator form. Is there any way to configure specific paths for login form?

Comment: You have to make the pattern match currently it is /adminpage that will never match /admin.

Comment: changed pattern to "/admin", processing-url to "/login", parameters to "username" and "password", but 404 still remained when sending post to admin/login with username and password parameters. Maybe I misunderstood you, can you provide an example?

Comment: After playing around, it finally worked. Thank you so much for you help. If you post an answer, I will mark it as a solution